# Python file size without opening file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Do both `os.stat` and `os.path.getsize` open and close the file to get this information? 
Is there a faster way to obtain the file size for large amounts of data without opening each file when I'm scanning the contents of terabytes of files?

Comment: No, they don't open the file.  Yes, there is a faster way than opening the file: use `os.stat()`.

Comment: For windows, or for Unix?

Comment: Sorry, this was for Windows. But eventually will make the same for Linux systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Linux, filesize is stored on the metadata on the file (precisely in the inode of the relevant file, maintained by the filesystem).

So, you don't need to open the file to get the file size, and `os.stat` and similar methods does not open the file to get the file size obviously. They simply do the `stat(2)` (and similar) system call underneath to read the inode data.